# Handles Me.Closing e.Cancel Is Failing With NotifyIcon

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, notifyicon

My program prompts the user to save info upon exit. If Yes is clicked > Program closes. If Cancel is clicked > Program stays open.

This is an example:

```
Private Sub Form_Close(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        e.Cancel = (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Exit?", "Backup Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No)
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above works fine, also this works fine (In the sense that if Yes or Cancel is clicked the program wont close):

```
Private Sub Form_Close(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
            e.Cancel = (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Exit?", "Backup Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No)
            e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End Sub
```

What I am having issues understanding after seeing how the above 2 both work is why this wont work:

```
Private Sub Form_Close(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        If e.CloseReason <> 0 Then
            e.Cancel = (MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Exit?", "Backup Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No)
        Else
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Upon form minimize e.CloseReason = 0 (Tested with MessageBox popups). So e.Cancel then equals True but the program closes itself down anyway!

The only ammendmant that my NotifyIcon makes is Me.Visible = False:

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
            Me.Visible = False
            NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Minimized To The Tray" & vbCrLf & "Click This Icon To Display The Main Screen"
            NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
        End If
End Sub
```

How can I prevent the program from closing while using a NotifyIcon in this way?

Comment: The question makes no sense, minimizing a form doesn't raise the FormClosing event.  Nor does comparing e.CloseReason to 0 make any sense, that's CloseReason.None.  I suspect that's the real hangup.

Comment: You're checking `If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then` minimizing the application. Maybe `If Me.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized Then` would make more sense.

Comment: If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then >> This is checking to see if the Form has been minimized for use with the NotifyIcon. It is the Me.Visible = False that is raising the Form.Closing event.

Comment: If Me.WindowState is minimized, why are you then setting it to Minimized again?  Me.Visible does not raise the forms Closing event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue:
I was loading a LoginForm.vb prior to Form1.vb. LoginForm.vb was using Form1.ShowDialog instead of Form1.Show() so that when I was minimizing Form1.vb it was actually minimizing the Form as a Dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Well first, as far as I can tell, hiding a form by setting its Visible property does not "close" the window. It merely hides the window while keeping the instance valid (though the handles of the window and its child controls AFAIK become invalid).

Second, virtually nothing will close a window with a CloseReason of None. A call to Form.Close() will have the reason UserClosing, just like clicking the X in the title bar. A call to Application.Exit() will have its own erason, and if the for is closing because its MDI parent or owner is, those have their own specific reasons. Even ending a program from the Task Manager or on Windows shutdown are known, differentiable reasons.

Are you 100% sure that your process terminates? Your code will pretty much prevent the app exiting completely unless the user has confirmed it. HOWEVER, it will not prevent the app being minimized to its tray icon; pretty much the only way you can intercept and cancel that in all cases is to override WndProc and look for WM_SHOWWINDOW messages with a WParam of 0 (hidden), and/or WM_SIZE messaages with a WParam of 1 (minimized). Setting the window state or visibility does not raise a cancellable .NET event like closing the window does.

Here's a basic app I created to test the behaviors you were seeing. Bottom line, I didn't have any problem minimizing this window (the app's main window) to its tray icon.

```
namespace BasicFormClosingTest
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            previousState = WindowState;
            if (WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            Visible = false;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Minimized To Tray";
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel =
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Form Closing for reason {0}. Do you want to cancel?", e.CloseReason),
                                "Closing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            WindowState = previousState == FormWindowState.Minimized ? FormWindowState.Normal : previousState;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
            this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // notifyIcon1
            // 
            this.notifyIcon1.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon1.Icon")));
            this.notifyIcon1.Text = "notifyIcon1";
            this.notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 52);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Minimize To Tray";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 82);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Close";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(31, 112);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(153, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button3.Text = "Exit Application";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private FormWindowState previousState;
    }
}
```